# Public domain children's songs

Tags: music, copyright, song

I am making videos and podcasts for children, want songs in the episodes, and have no budget for a musician or to buy copyrighted music. My preferred alternative is to use melodies from children's songs from folklore around the world that are in the public domain. If that does not exist, I could spend some time scraping Wikipedia articles with audio files, or start with the [list of English nursery rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_children%27s_songs).

Does a repository of public domain children's folklore music exist?

Comment: I think it's important to understand that copyright for music is split into two different forms: composition and recording. A composition can be public domain but that doesn't mean that any recordings you find of that song will also be public domain. You need to be sure that both the composition AND the recording are public domain or you'll need to make your own recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I programmed a Python scraper of audio files on Wikipedia pages such as:

- [List of nursery rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nursery_rhymes)
- [List of playground songs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_playground_songs)
- [Counting-out game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting-out_game)
- [Repetitive song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_song)
- [Cumulative song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_song)
- [Round music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_(music))

I listened to them and chose interesting ones. Then I searched for the date and author information and crossed it with [this list of children songs in the public domain](https://www.pdinfo.com/pd-music-genres/pd-children-songs.php).

For more details about law and copyright of children's folklore songs, read these two threads from the Law StackExchange: [Copyright of children's folklore songs](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57046/copyright-of-childrens-folklore-songs/57056#57056) and [Copyright of a children's song with no author or date](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57670/copyright-of-a-childrens-song-with-no-author-or-date-information/57674#57674).